errors finding package when using tox for testing with cython extensions
I am using cython to build a module for a library. When I install the package locally, i.e., pip install . I can perfectly import and run the module, however I cannot do that in tox environments.
Locally I get a ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pylandstats.adjacency', whereas in GitHub Actions i get a ValueError: 'pylandstats/adjacency.pyx' doesn't match any files (see the latest run with verbose tox).
You can find the tox config at pyproject.toml, cython extension at setup.py and GitHub Actions workflow at .github/workflows/tests.yml here: https://github.com/martibosch/pylandstats/pull/60
How can I fix this? Thanks in advance!

I'm not 100% sure that your configuration actually asks tox to install your package as expected. Have you tried using the commands_pre tox configuration to actually install your package in your tox env? this way you can make sure it's installed correcly before running tests (see commands_pre from the tox documentation https://tox.wiki/en/latest/config.html#commands_pre)

I do not understand: the package is clearly being installed (https://github.com/martibosch/pylandstats/actions/runs/12134965566/job/33833105034?pr=60#step:4:412), however for some reason the build_sdist command that tox runs (https://github.com/martibosch/pylandstats/actions/runs/12134965566/job/33833105034?pr=60#step:4:226) does not include adjacency.pyx (instead running python -m build . locally does). I tried including the pyx files (not sure that makes sense) and then the package is installed but ModuleNotFoundError happens in tests. Should I try to force tox to use python -m build?

It's more of a guess from my side, I think you should try to force tox to install it using commands_pre to see if it helps. I didn't try myself using tox from pyproject.toml in addition to setuptools, so I might be wrong here, but usually when I want a package to be installed in a specific way in tox that's how I do it.
